# What exactly is sudo bang bang?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, sh

What is the purpose of sudo bang bang (`sudo !!`) and when might one need to use it?

[image: make me a sandwich, sudo bang bang]

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The bang bang (`!!`) command is a shortcut to **repeat the previous command you entered in your terminal**. This command is very useful when you forget that you need admin rights to make a certain action, and lets you repeat it with super-user rights just by typing

```
sudo !!
```

instead of typing arrow-up, scrolling to the beginning of the line, adding `sudo`  and hitting enter (imagine scrolling through those *loooong* `apt-get` commands). So many seconds gained! *Yay!*

[image: sudo bang bang]

There are many other bang-commands such as `!x`, `!?x`, `!!:p` and `!!*`. This [blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20130731111822/https://craig-russell.co.uk/2011/09/28/bang-bang-command-recall-in-linux.html) lists them and explains what they are for.

Comment: Note: `ctrl+a` jumps to the start of the line so you don't have jump back one character at a time.

Comment: @sudo_O Surprisingly many developers don't know that either

Comment: And `ctrl+e` jumps back at the end of the line (and there are many more useful options!)

Comment: And `ctrl+r` matches last commands used.

Comment: `home` also jumps to the start of the line.

Comment: Recently I've noticed that `ctrl+a` and `ctrl+e` work pretty much everywhere. Text editors, browsers, etc.

Comment: I discovered those less than two months ago!

Comment: @sudo_O wat... mind blown. However, in what shells do `HOME` and `END` not work?

Comment: @JulianH.Lam yes [here](http://www.bigsmoke.us/readline/shortcuts) are all the readline keyboard shortcuts. `HOME` and `END` work for me, depends on shell, set up, ect..

Comment: @JulianH.Lam terminal for mac home scrolls all the way to the top of the session .. although mac keyboards don't even have home keys .. but I think `fn` and left arrow key is the same

Comment: note: this is a bash builtin feature, that you can unset with `set +o histexpand`.

Comment: I use `set -o vi`, so `ctrl+a` and `ctrl+e` insert nonsense characters, while `0` and `$` jump to start/end of line.

Comment: @pythonian29033 what are you trying to say? Answering your own question is highly encouraged

Comment: I know, I did the same a couple years back lol

Comment: @JulianH.Lam in the Windows SSH client PuTTY `HOME` and `END` don't work properly.

Comment: Yes... as I've come to realise in the past 4 years, there are other development environments besides my own. My reply up there in 2013 seems awfully small-minded.

Comment: You can also hold down left arrow, ctrl+b, or alt+b to get to the beginning of the line (◠﹏◠)

Comment: @luizfls HOME and END work for me in Windows SSH PuTTY

Comment: @mbomb007 I'm SSHing into a CentOS 6 machine and when I hit `HOME` or `END`, what I get is a `~`.

Comment: @luizfls Have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/104001/494173)? Or are you using Home and End [on a numpad](https://superuser.com/a/1159876/494173)? There's also a setting in Terminal > Keyboard.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks! The first link did it. :-)